# How to provide auto-complete option for pre-defined filter values when using MUI data grid filter

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I'm new to the react and MUI community.
I'm working on a dashboard using react and MUI where Im displaying records from database. I have added a MUI Data grid filter to enable user to search for a specific record by selecting the column name in the filter field and entering a value in the filter value box. I would like to know, how to dynamically show options in the filter value field. For example, if I chose the filter column as City, when the user starts typing "New" in the filter search value, I should suggest "New Orleans", "New York" as options.

I have tried adding valueOptions and type properties to the column fields but that did not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.